# Online Judge do mistake?

Tags: c++

well 
as i keep saying i am a new C++ programmer 
while i am solving simple problem to shave my skills or whatever you guys call it ...
i face this strange thing that keep happen 
the online judge keep giving me a wrong answer ...

now to be sure i am doing everything right 
i debug and use many inputs and every time i get the right output .

now i will give u a simple code i right that give me an error with a link that contain the description of the 
problem .

let's start with the link : http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/repository/UOJ_1036_en.html
now the code :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

void Formula(float v1, float v2, float b);

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    //making the variables ....
    float a, b, c;
    float v1, v2;

    //reading the variables
    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    //assign v1,v2
    v1 = (pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c));
    v2 = 2 * a;

    //making sure that i can use V1 , V2
    if (v1 < 0 || v2 == 0) {
        cout << "Impossivel calcular" << endl;
    } //end of the if condition .....
    else {
        //at this condition i will call a function that calculate the square root(s)
        Formula(v1, v2, b);
    } //end of the else condition

    return 0;
} //end of the main method.....

//////////////////////////
//////////////////////////
//////////////////////////

//making the methods
void Formula(float v1, float v2, float b) {
    //first square root...
    float result = -b + sqrt(v1);
    result /= v2;
    cout << "R1 = " << fixed << setprecision(5) << result << endl;
    //second square root ...
    result = -b - sqrt(v1);
    result /= v2;
    cout << "R1 = " << fixed << setprecision(5) << result << endl;
} //end of the method .....
```

well this is the most simple example ... 
now it can be my error cause i am new to C/C++ 
and please if there's anything wrong 
tell me and what is the best input i should i try with most of the cases ?

Comment: What error did you get? This runs fine for me and out puts "Impossivel calcular"

Comment: xD well this is the trick it doesn't give me an error sir
the online judge say it does 
and if u don't know online judge after i finish writing the code ...
i submit it and it test it and tell me if it's write or wrong ..

Comment: Replace all `float` into `double` and `pow(b, 2)` into `(b*b)` to improve floating point precision.

Comment: well about the float i can't change it cause the asked for it in the problem description
read 4 floating point . is that right so i have to use float but about the pow i will do ..

Comment: `double` is double-precision floating point numbers. You _can_ change. The problem statement only lets you know that it's not an integer. Also, `v2 == 0` is problematic due to rounding error.

Comment: ok i will try this now one second

Comment: See my answer. At least make you output format _exactly_ the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Formula(float v1, float v2, float b) {
    //first square root...
    float result = -b + sqrt(v1);
    result /= v2;
    cout << "R1 = " << fixed << setprecision(5) << result << endl;
    //second square root ...
    result = -b - sqrt(v1);
    result /= v2;
    cout << "R1 = " << fixed << setprecision(5) << result << endl;
} //end of the method .....
```

Modify the 2nd `R1 =` into `R2 =`.